# Swift 4 to Swift 5 Xcode errors

Tags: swift, xcode

I've upgraded my Swift 4.0 project to Swift 5.0 project by changing the language's version in the project and then I reinstalled the cocoapods.
Now in my Swift 5.0 project, there isn't the file SceneDelegate, there is only the AppDelegate which is from Swift 4.0 project (because SceneDelegate has been implemented in swift 5).
When I try to run the project the Xcode shows the following errors:

[image: screenshot that shows errors]

How can I solve?

Comment: 1. SceneDelegate has nothing to do with your Swift version. It's something that was introduced in iOS 13. 2. Don't post screenshots; copy the text of the errors and include them in your post. 3. Your problem is that your app needs to link against `libz` and is not.

Comment: I’d also make sure to empty the derived data folder and restart Xcode. Sometimes these object files (the `.o` files) aren’t rebuilt as necessary. Emptying derived data and restarting will ensure they are.